# Omniture tagging - Fire a start event on Onchange (Not Working !!!!)

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am a newbie to Omniture tagging. The company has provided specs and I am following that. I want to fire a start event when the value in the dropdown changes. I don't know what I am missing because it refuses fire the event. I am using Omnibug to test.

```
   <select name="seltest" onChange = "var s=s_gi('ds-prod');tmsomni.linkTrackVars= 
     'prop6,prop64';tmsomni.linkTrackEvents = 'event54';tmsomni.prop6 = 'vehicle
    request';tmsomni.prop64 = 'vehicle'; s.tl(true, 'o');">

 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the tracking object to s and then using tmsomni to set values in the tracking object. It should look more like this:

```
<select name="seltest" onchange="window.tmsomni=s_gi('ds-prod');tmsomni.linkTrackVars= 'prop6,prop64';tmsomni.linkTrackEvents = 'event54';tmsomni.prop6 = 'vehicle request';tmsomni.prop64 = 'vehicle'; tmsomni.tl(true, 'o');">

 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
  </select>
```

Or perhaps the inverse where you would replace all tmsomni with s.

Comment: That did not work, I tried both options. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Thanks. Tried that too but no success :(

Comment: What analytics library are you loading and how are you loading it? Are you getting any errors in your javascript console in your browser? I loaded that code in a test site and it works so something else has to be happening too.

Comment: No I am not getting any errors. The analytics library is given by the client. I also feel it should work. Working with the clients programmer to figure it out. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Also set the events variable as below:

```
<select name="seltest" onchange="window.tmsomni=s_gi('ds-prod');tmsomni.linkTrackVars= 'prop6,prop64';tmsomni.linkTrackEvents = 'event54';tmsomni.events = 'event54';tmsomni.prop6 = 'vehicle request';tmsomni.prop64 = 'vehicle'; tmsomni.tl(true, 'o');">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked , I was missing the name of the link.